# unable to redirect to an external URI in java

Tags: java, rest, redirect

so I have given a task that I should redirect a client to bank portal without using spring MVC. i have found javax.ws.rs.core.Response class that might help me! but the problem is the redirection is totally wrong and I also couldn't find a proper solution for this on google!

this is my service

```
@Path("/ag/v1")
public class testService {


@GET
@Path("/test")
public Response redirectTest(){
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("www.google.com").build();
    return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
}

}
```

this service redirect a client to localhost:8080/api/www.google.com   ! but I want to redirect it to www.google.com!

is there another best way?
 how can i fix this ?
can you please guide me?

Comment: can you try with http:// : UriBuilder.fromUri("\http://www.google.com").build();

Comment: Javadocs say `"location - the redirection URI. If a relative URI is supplied it will be converted into an absolute URI by resolving it relative to the base URI of the application (see UriInfo.getBaseUri())."`. You probably need to add the scheme (`https://www.google.com/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you write address without http your code is redirecting the User to a URL inside your project.

you can use two way to correct this:

1: you can write http:// for redirecting out side your project.

2: you can set response status with 302

The HTTP response status code 302 is a common way of performing URL redirection